# Is my code fine in the areas of read and write?

Tags: c++, performance, beginner

**What:**

This is a code that when executed simply writes `packet` to certain file types. Packet is very simple and contains things like:

```
description, partCount, price...
```

**Please:**

1. Ignore the usage of namespace std; as this is for educational
   purposes, mostly. It will most likely not be reproduced in a real
   program.
2. Focus on reviewing the read and write portions as I would love
   feedback on those portions.
3. I used some other things for simplicity, but in general I am mainly
   looking for feedback on read/write portions of the code.

**Intent:**

I'm specifically *looking for feedback on the read and write portions of the code.* Could I get feedback on it as well as is it feasible as a piece of code and what can I improve on/etc.???

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#include "Packet.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Input and Output Filing System" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    fstream bOutFile;
    vector<Packet> package;
    Packet one(0, "A packet of cheese.", 21.99, 4);
    package.push_back(one);
    Packet two(1, "A packet of super-cheese.", 31.99, 2);
    package.push_back(two);

    cout << "Starting to write packets to file..." << endl;

    outFile.open("Insert Your Destination of File Here.Txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < package.size(); ++i) {
        outFile << "{" << endl;
        outFile << package[i].getPartId() << "," << endl;
        outFile << package[i].getDescription() << "," << endl;
        outFile << package[i].getPartCount() << "," << endl;
        outFile << package[i].getPrice() << "," << endl;
        outFile << "}" << endl << endl;
    }
    outFile.close();

    cout << "Starting to read packets from file..." << endl;

    inFile.open("Insert Your Destination of File Here.Txt");
    string line;
    while (getline(inFile, line)) {
        if (line[0] != '{' && line[0] != '}') {
            cout << line.substr(0, line.size() - 1) << endl;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();

    cout << "Starting to write packets to binary..." << endl;

    bOutFile.open("Insert Your Destination of File Here.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
    for (int i = 0; i < package.size(); ++i) {
        bOutFile.write((char*)&package[i], sizeof(package[i]));
    }
    bOutFile.close();

    system("pause");
}
```

**Packet.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Packet {
public:
    Packet(int partId, string description, double price, int partCount) :
        partId(partId), description(description), price(price), partCount(partCount) {}
    int getPartId() const { return partId; }
    string getDescription() const { return description; }
    double getPrice() const { return price; }
    int getPartCount() const { return partCount; }

private:
    int partId;
    string description;
    double price;
    int partCount;
};
```

Comment: Why should we ignore `using namespace std`? It is bad, no matter what program you write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < package.size(); ++i)
```

I'd use for (auto& p : package) instead if the index (i) is not used for anything.

```
outFile << package[i].getPartId() << "," << endl;
```

Remember that std::endl flushes the stream. This is very minor, but I'd use a manual '\n' and then flush when the whole object is written.

```
bOutFile.write((char*)&package[i], sizeof(package[i]));
```

This is I do not like at all. Copying objects like this is problematic when you have objects with more complex data. I.e. pointers or dynamically allocated memory.

Take a look at serialization/deserialization, I found this read quite good concerning the topic: https://rubentorresbonet.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/an-overview-of-data-serialization-techniques-in-c/

```
Packet(int partId, string description, double price, int partCount
```

Make the passed arguments const references instead! (Otherwise an extra copy will be done)

Comment: Thanks, I will make note of this. But also here's the thing: "Make the passed arguments const references instead! (Otherwise an extra copy will be done)" this shouldn't be the case for int, string, double, and int...They're primitives. It would only apply to objects and similar things like objects.